# Run telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to run telegram bot

```
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper

apihelper.proxy = {"http": "http://{}".format(proxy)}
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeating_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

But it returns

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url
```

How I can avoid it? I've tried to use all cases from GitHub, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you can't connect to the telegram API. What kind of network are you on? Where does `proxy` come from in your example?

Comment: suggest you reading more [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

Comment: @AKX i'm checking proxies from https://www.us-proxy.org on the google url and get working

Comment: @Kendoka the connection aren't established

Comment: you can't visit the site [https://core.telegram.org/bots/api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) ???

Comment: @Kendoka telegram is blocked in some countries.

Comment: @awesoon that's what i was saying

Comment: @Kendoka then why are you surprised that `https://core.telegram.org/bots/api` is also unaccessible?

Comment: @awesoon I'm not surprised I was re-asking to be clear :)